# Transfer of data between C++ application and server

Tags: c++, json, libcurl

I have an application that generates data and i'd like to transfer this to a database. The application is written in C++. I'm considering packaging up the data into JSON format and then sending that via libCurl to a server running PHP via a HTTP POST request. The data to be transferred is not that large. Maybe 100K/day.

Have others done something similar? Maybe there are better alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a look at having your c++ application talk directly to your MySQL database with [MySQL++](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/). This library is essentially a wrapper around the MySQL C API with an LGPL license.

You could also expose access to the database via a webservice with a Restful API, which would go nicely with handling the json data.

Comment: Thanks. MySQL++ looks like it could be very useful.